# Find all $n$ such that $n/d(n) = p$, a prime, where $d(n)$ is the number of positive divisors of $n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, prime-factorization

> Let $d(n)$ denote the number of positive divisors of $n$. Find all $n$ such that $n/d(n) = p$, a prime.

I tried this, but only I could get two solutions.
I proceeded like this -

Suppose 
$$n = p^r \cdot p_1^{r_1} \cdot \cdots \cdot p_k^{r_k}$$ 
where the $p_i$s are distinct primes.

Given 
$$n=p\cdot d(n)=p(r+1)(r_1+1)\cdots (r_k+1)$$
$$p^r \cdots p_1^{r_1}\cdot \cdots \cdot p_k^{r_k}=(r+1)(r_1+1)\cdots(r_k+1)$$
If $k=0$, then $p^(r-1)=r+1$. Hence $p=2$ and $r=3$, or $p=3$ and $r=2$. I.e., $n=8$, or $n=9$.

But, when I am assuming $k>0$, I am finding no clue.

For this, I need help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you believe the list is sensible?  For $n=84$ we get $7$.  For $n=88$ we get $11$.  For $n=156$ you get $13$.  I stopped looking after that,

Comment: then maybe you will get a general form, something like 4k, or 9k+ 1 numbers.... (i am giving an example)

Comment: Seems that $9$ is the only odd such number (I have no proof yet), but there are plenty of even numbers satisfying the condition giving no obvious pattern except that $18$ seems to be the only even example which is not divisible by $4$.

Comment: But this is a standard question from one of the most famous math institues of our country, Indian Statistical Institute.. Obviously there is something, which i am unable to make out

Comment: Did you find 18 by trial and error?

Comment: With PARI/GP and brute force, yes , trial and error

Comment: Yeah. I did not find any more interesting approach

Comment: I suggest:  Make a list of the first ten or twenty even examples, along with their factoring.  Maybe a pattern emerges.  As it stands, the question is too vague to do much with.

Comment: That will be a conjecture then!

Comment: I have already guessed about numbers of the form 4k and 8k, but cannot prove it

Comment: I don't see where you have made a conjecture about numbers of the form $4k,8k$.  Note:  all numbers of the form $8p$ where $p$ is prime work (trivially).

Comment: @lulu Except for $\ p=2\ $:)

Comment: Also , $12p$ for every prime $p\ge 5$ works.

Comment: 12p can  be written in 4q form, that was what is was trying to say

Comment: But cant it be proved

Comment: Seems that $8,9,12,18$ , $8p$ with prime $p\ge 3$ and $12p$ with prime $p\ge 5$ are all the solutions. But how can it be proven ? Other solutions , if existent, must exceed $10^8$

Comment: Have you looked at http://oeis.org/A063080 ?

Comment: No it is in a preparatory booklet of my exam

Comment: Then I suggest you look at it now. It might give you some insight, it might not.

Comment: Yeah! It goes perfectly as i and peter conjectured... numbers of form 4p, 8q with some exceptions!

Answer (score 2):

**Observation 1**. It is easy to prove (e.g. by induction) that:
$$p^n \geq n+1, \forall p\geq2, \forall n\geq 1$$
Thus
$$p^r\cdot \color{blue}{p_1^{r_1}\cdot ... \cdot p_k^{r_k}}=
p(r+1)\cdot \color{blue}{(r_1+1)...(r_k+1)}\geq 
p^r \cdot \color{blue}{(r_1+1)...(r_k+1)}$$
or
$$p(r+1)\geq p^r \iff r+1\geq p^{r-1}$$
These are the only $(r,p)$ combinations possible $(1,2), (2,2), (3,2)$ then $(1,3),(2,3)$ and finally $(1,p), \forall p>3, p$ - prime.

---

**Observation 2**. Let's check the following case $(1,p), \forall p>3, p$ - prime (i.e. $r=1$).

$$p\cdot \color{blue}{p_1^{r_1}\cdot ... \cdot p_k^{r_k}}=
p\cdot 2\cdot \color{blue}{(r_1+1)...(r_k+1)} \iff \\
p_1^{r_1}\cdot ... \cdot p_k^{r_k}=
2\cdot (r_1+1)...(r_k+1) \iff ...$$
or [one of the](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) $p_i=2$, for simplicity let's say $p_1=2$.
$$... \iff 2^{r_1-1}\cdot \color{blue}{p_2^{r_2} ... \cdot p_k^{r_k}}=
(r_1+1)\color{blue}{(r_2+1)...(r_k+1)}\geq 
 2^{r_1-1}\cdot \color{blue}{(r_2+1)...(r_k+1)}$$
or again
$$(r_1+1)\geq 2^{r_1-1}$$
or $r_1 \in \{1,2,3\}$.

This reduces the problem to the following cases $(1,2), (2,2), (3,2)$ then $(1,3),(2,3)$.

Comment: Wrong solution. Check 8,18

Comment: Which solution? This is an **observation** which narrows down the search space.

Comment: Sorry i didnt read that